# Raspberry Pi thermal throttle

Tags: raspbian, temperature

I am running Raspian 9.4 Stretch and access it through SSH. How can I determine whether my RaspberryPi (3B+) is currently in a state of thermal throttle? I know I can get the RasPi's temperature using `vcgencmd measure_temp`, but what is the actual temperature target, when the Pi starts throttling? Is this target temperature something that is determined by the OS I am currently using? Or is it defined inside the SoC's firmware? How could I read it from the firmware? Can I change it? Is there a way to get the thermal throttle indicator from Raspian GUI inside SSH terminal?

Unfortunately the `vcgencmd get_throttled` command seems not to include all throttle states. e.g. I get this when NOT using a fan for cooling: 

`$ vcgencmd measure_clock arm && vcgencmd measure_temp && vcgencmd get_throttled 
frequency(45)=1200000000 
temp=70.4'C 
throttled=0x0`

and this when using a fan: 

`$ vcgencmd measure_clock arm && vcgencmd measure_temp && vcgencmd get_throttled 
frequency(45)=1400000000 
temp=62.3'C 
throttled=0x0`

CPU throttles down from 1.4 GHz to 1.2 GHz, but `vcgencmd get_throttled` still shows 0x0.

Answer (score 5):

Try `vcgencmd get_throttled`

See https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=147781&start=50#p972790 which shows

```
    0: under-voltage
    1: arm frequency capped
    2: currently throttled
    16: under-voltage has occurred
    17: arm frequency capped has occurred
    18: throttling has occurred
```

Comment: The CPU does not throttle down until it hits 80 C.  I think you are confusing the effect of the "on demand" governor for throttling.

Comment: I am currently using BOINC to get a load on my RasPi CPU. What I am observing is, that below 70°C the CPU works with 1.4 GHz. But as soon as the temperature exceeds 70°C the CPU "throttles" to 1.2 GHz. I do not know how else I could describe this behaviour if not with "throttling"

Comment: @jschfr **DO NOT** paste detail in Comments - Edit into your question.

Answer (score 2):

> what is the actual temperature target, when the Pi starts throttling?

[According to this post from an Rpi engineer](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=82373&p=582328) (which is quite old, but appears to have been updated in 2016), the CPU is throttled at 80 C and the GPU at 85 C.  This makes sense as it is unlikely they would do it unreasonably within the confines of the operating parameters (safe up to 85 C) but would not want to allow it to go far beyond that point either.  I.e., it is not intended to take effect when the system is just getting warm, it is intended to take effect when it is getting *too hot*.

> Is this target temperature something that is determined by the OS I am currently using?

That post explicitly refers to firmware, so no, it is not the OS.  You may still be able to configure it using the setting mentioned there (this would be in `config.txt`).  Although it is not clear that you could raise it beyond 85 C, you can at least test it by lowering it via `temp_limit`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation on frequency management,](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/frequency-management.md) the 3B+ model has a "soft" temperature limit of 60C. It will throttle down to 1.2 GHz when it goes above that. The intent is to allow more time operating at 1.2 GHz before hitting
the harder limit of 80C and throttling further.

I'm not sure why you're seeing a limit at 70 instead, maybe it's been changed somehow. You can try setting the soft limit in /boot/config.txt like so:

```
temp_soft_limit=75
```